# subset S of a MST of a given graph

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Is a subset S of a MST of a given graph necessarily a collection of trees which are MSTs of the graph defined by the edges included in S, component by component?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right, if I understand you correctly.  Have you tried to prove it?

Comment: So I've asked my teacher and it seems that this is what's colled optimal substructure propriety. Since the propriety is necessary for building a greedy algorithm and MSTs can be built with greedy algorithms, it would seem to verify. I actually used this propriety for proving the uniqueness of MSTs in weighted graphs with distinct weights in a way that was different than standard, but needed confirmation.